# Error code: %d expected type int, but argument has type int *

Tags: c

I have an error code I do not understand:

```
format %d expects type int, but argument 2 has type int *
```

I do not know the difference between `int` and `int *`.  I did not know there were different types of `int`, and cannot find any note of it on webpages about `printf` and `scanf` key letters.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int X = 0, Y = 0, A = 0, D = 0;        
    printf("This program computes the area of a rectangle ");
    printf("and its diagonal length.");
    printf("Enter Side 1 dimentions: ");
    scanf("%d", &X);
    printf("Enter Side 2 dimentions: ");
    scanf("%d", &Y);

    /* Calc */
    A = X * Y;
    D = pow(X,2) + pow(Y,2);    
    D = pow(D, 1 / 2);    

    /* Output */
    printf("Rectangle Area is %d sq. units.", &A);  
    printf(" Diagonal length is %d.", &D);  
    return 0;
}
```

The error references the last two printf's:

```
printf("Rectangle Area is %d sq. units.", &A);  
printf(" Diagonal length is %d.", &D);
```

Additionally, this program was originally written using floats (declaring X,Y,A, and D as float and using %f).  But that gave an even stranger error code:
format %f expects type double, but argument 2 has type float *

I knew that %f is used for doubles and floats, so I could not understand why I had this error.  After I got the error code about floats/doubles I tried changing everything to int (as shown in the above code), just to check.  But that delivered the error code at the top of this post, which I do not understand either.

I've been using the gcc compiler.
Would someone explain what's being done wrong?

Comment: The first error includes the types `int` and `int *`, not `int` and `int`...

Comment: `int` is an integer type. `int*` is a pointer type. An object of type `int` contains an integer value. An object of type `int*` contains the address of some object of type `int` (or a null pointer that doesn't point to anything).

Comment: When you copy-and-pasted the error messages, some of the non-ASCII characters were rendered incorrectly (probably some conversion was incorrectly performed twice). I've cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to pass pointers to the `printf` function. Here's what your code looks like:

```
printf("Rectangle Area is %d sq. units.", &A);  
printf(" Diagonal length is %d.", &D);
```

`A` is the int variable, but `&A` is a pointer to the int variable. What you want is this:

```
printf("Rectangle Area is %d sq. units.", A);  
printf(" Diagonal length is %d.", D);
```

Answer (score 1):

int* means a **pointer** to an int object. this is what you get because you use & before the variable name (i.e &A in your code)

You can read [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) to understand more about pointers and references, but basically if you omit the & before the variable names, it will work fine.

Comment: An `int` isn't an object, it's a primitive type. So it's incorrect where you say "int object".

Comment: @Gavin: `int` is a type. *An* `int` is an object whose type is `int`. An `int*` object or value points to an object of type `int` -- i.e., to an `int` object.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think it depends on your definition of "object". Technically in C, nothing's an object because it's not an object-oriented language. If we were looking at an object-oriented language, there is generally some wrapper class that wraps a primitive type in an object, but `int` itself would be a primitive type, and wouldn't be an object.

Comment: @Gavin: The C standard defines the word "object" as a "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values". The C++ standard's definition is similar, and has nothing to do with object-oriented programming. Given `int n;`, `int` is a type, and `n` is the name of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Why passing pointers to printf("...%d...", &D)?

Take a look to pointers explanation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Pointers

And to simplified printf() manual:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```c
int d = 1;
printf("I'm an integer: %d", 42);           // OK, prints "...42"
printf("I'm an integer too: %d", d);        // OK, prints "...1"
printf("I'm a pointer, I have no idea why you printing me: %p", (void*)&d); // OK, prints "...<address of d>", probably not what you want

printf("I'm compile-time error: %d", &d);   // Fail, prints comiper error: 'int' reqired, but &d is 'int*'
```